# WordPress - How to replace all wp.me shortlinks?

Tags: wordpress

I have a website which is hosted at wordpress.com and I want to transfer this one to an own hosted environment. The current website on wordpress.com includes a ton of links which are shortened with wp.me and have been used to link from a page to another page/post.

I want to change the internal links to "normal" links, because otherwise the links are directing still to the site at wordpress.com. How can I do that? Is there a way to do this (semi-)automatically? Any chance to get a table that shows the permalink and the corresponding shortlink?

Thanks!

Comment: Write a function to get all the links in the db,use curl in a foreach to pass them to an url expander service and get the results back.Yes,it needs some work.

Comment: Which service do you recommend @Mihai ?

Comment: I dont know use something like this http://www.checkshorturl.com/

Answer (score 0):

you can use [this script](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/), I think it's the best for wordpress migrations.

1. Download
2. Create a new folder in the server root directory
3. Upload the files in to that directory
4. Type the correct url www.yoursite/yourdirectory
5. Enter the current url in your DB and the new Url
6. Click in dry run and then live run

Remember to download a copy of the DB.

Comment: Mauro, that makes no sense. I have a lot of wp.me links in the database in wp_posts -> post_content and I need to get the deeplink of those wp.me links in order to replace them in the database...